# How can I obtain a variable from the installer of a visual studio 2013 c# project?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, installation, installshield

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with a wpf C# project type. My goal is that during installation of my software, I can have a prompt for a variable that will be a unc path. Basically during install, I will be setting the path to the server data directory that this program will be working with

On the installer just a text box with a label next to it that I can store the value of in the registry during install or access from within the code.

"ServerPath"    \\servername\someshare.

I have scoured the net for days and tried installshield LE as well as the basic visual studio installer with configuration -> application settings, but I can't seem to find a way to accomplish what seems to be simple.

Anybody know how I can do this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So... ClickOnce doesn't allow you to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the Visual Studio Installer add-on for VS 2013 (not InstallShield) then this is the normal way using that tool:

1. Create a textbox dialog in the setup project using Add Dialog. It looks like you have already got that far.
2. That dialog (say it's the TEXTBOXES(A) dialog) has a properties window where the text the user enters is associated with properties with names like EDITA1, EDITA2 etc.
3. Create your registry entry where you need it using the registry view with a name of your choice and give it the case-sensitive value of [EDITA1] and that results in the actual value being stored in the registry.

One of the downsides of these VS setup projects is that you cannot validate that input as it's entered, so validation is awkward.

Comment: Thanks Phil, this helped me! Banging my head against the wall for a few days researching to find nothing.

Comment: Quick question. Once again I'm stuck : (  I downloaded the Visual Studio 2013 extension that brings back the setup project you were referencing. But How do I get to the "Add Dialog" section? I can't find it anywhere. What menus do you go to to open it?

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind I found it. For those who may wonder go to the User Interface Editor and right click on a category of dialog (Like Start Progress or End) and from there click Add Dialog. I was trying to insert it between existing dialogs and wasn't receiving the option.

Answer (score 0):

To get the path set in your setup text box during installation, you can create a [C# custom action](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jschaffe/archive/2012/10/23/creating-wix-custom-actions-in-c-and-passing-parameters.aspx) and access within its code the value of the property associated with your text box control. To get and set installer properties within a C# code you can follow this example:

```
public static ActionResult CustomAction1(Session session)
{
// get property
Variable = session["PROPERTY"];

// set property
session["PROPERTY"] = variable;

return ActionResult.Success;
}
```